# Black screen when logging into desktop

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, kde, xrandr

On [Kubuntu 15.10](http://kubuntu.com/) I receive a black screen when logging in via the Display Manager. I can use Ctrl-Alt-F6 to log into a text console and see my files, but even in that environment when I type `startx` the screen just goes blank and nothing further happens. I have renamed my `~/.kde` directory to `~/.kde-old` but the problem still persists.

The display manager has a setting "failsafe", when I try to log in with it set I just get booted back to the display manager screen again after a few seconds.

[Here is dmesg](http://pastebin.com/ZxT1hynp), I've pasted what I think are the relevant lines below but clicking on the link will bring you to Pastebin where the entire log is stored.

```
[  117.572448] kscreen_backend[1626]: segfault at 10 ip 00007f8c0cf068c0 sp 00007ffdfd0ed358 error 4 in KSC_XRandR.so[7f8c0cef3000+20000]
[  118.556865] kactivitymanage[1610]: segfault at 18 ip 00007fdc57430ee0 sp 00007ffde65b6878 error 4 in libqxcb.so[7fdc57402000+b5000]
[  118.569140] krunner[1633]: segfault at 18 ip 00007fcd52973e38 sp 00007ffed1ec3370 error 4 in libqxcb.so[7fcd5292a000+b5000]
[  118.572032] kdeconnectd[1632]: segfault at 18 ip 00007fcb022f3e38 sp 00007ffc58549500 error 4 in libqxcb.so[7fcb022aa000+b5000]
[  118.578476] kscreen_backend[1639]: segfault at 18 ip 00007f0956e02e38 sp 00007ffc3a121980 error 4 in libqxcb.so[7f0956db9000+b5000]
[  118.578622] kwin_x11[1629]: segfault at 18 ip 00007f2f5d039e38 sp 00007ffcf6c160e0 error 4 in libqxcb.so[7f2f5cff0000+b5000]
[  118.998290] plasmashell[1655]: segfault at 18 ip 00007f39a8edae38 sp 00007ffcf531f110 error 4 in libqxcb.so[7f39a8e91000+b5000]
[  120.469171] kglobalaccel5[1685]: segfault at 18 ip 00007fc6917f1e38 sp 00007fffb2965630 error 4 in libqxcb.so[7fc6917a8000+b5000]
[  120.475815] kglobalaccel5[1687]: segfault at 18 ip 00007f7b14409e38 sp 00007ffe5d3a59f0 error 4 in libqxcb.so[7f7b143c0000+b5000]
[  120.735669] kglobalaccel5[1700]: segfault at 18 ip 00007fde7578ae38 sp 00007ffe9d3d7520 error 4 in libqxcb.so[7fde75741000+b5000]
[  124.165384] show_signal_msg: 2 callbacks suppressed
[  124.165389] korgac[1719]: segfault at 18 ip 00007f4e33530e38 sp 00007ffe1e69b010 error 4 in libqxcb.so[7f4e334e7000+b5000]
[  124.203178] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0b1: link is not ready
[  124.821375] wlp5s0b1: authenticate with b0:48:7a:fd:99:ae
[  124.823047] wlp5s0b1: direct probe to b0:48:7a:fd:99:ae (try 1/3)
[  125.023234] wlp5s0b1: direct probe to b0:48:7a:fd:99:ae (try 2/3)
[  125.227080] wlp5s0b1: direct probe to b0:48:7a:fd:99:ae (try 3/3)
[  125.431014] wlp5s0b1: authentication with b0:48:7a:fd:99:ae timed out
[  125.627814] korgac[1727]: segfault at 18 ip 00007f0294472e38 sp 00007ffeec678ea0 error 4 in libqxcb.so[7f0294429000+b5000]
[  127.951872] klauncher[1774]: segfault at 18 ip 00007f25f91b2e38 sp 00007fffc3569a90 error 4 in libqxcb.so[7f25f9169000+b5000]
[  136.059194] wlp5s0b1: authenticate with b0:48:7a:fd:99:ae
[  136.059317] wlp5s0b1: direct probe to b0:48:7a:fd:99:ae (try 1/3)
[  136.261035] wlp5s0b1: direct probe to b0:48:7a:fd:99:ae (try 2/3)
[  136.464894] wlp5s0b1: direct probe to b0:48:7a:fd:99:ae (try 3/3)
[  136.668804] wlp5s0b1: authentication with b0:48:7a:fd:99:ae timed out
[  149.191322] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0b1: link is not ready
[  149.816413] wlp5s0b1: authenticate with b0:48:7a:fd:99:ae
[  149.816517] wlp5s0b1: direct probe to b0:48:7a:fd:99:ae (try 1/3)
[  150.017451] wlp5s0b1: direct probe to b0:48:7a:fd:99:ae (try 2/3)
[  150.221322] wlp5s0b1: direct probe to b0:48:7a:fd:99:ae (try 3/3)
[  150.425210] wlp5s0b1: authentication with b0:48:7a:fd:99:ae timed out
[  152.779659] kscreen_backend[1965]: segfault at 10 ip 00007f253f78c8c0 sp 00007ffe7a87d1b8 error 4 in KSC_XRandR.so[7f253f779000+20000]
[  152.941924] kactivitymanage[1952]: segfault at 18 ip 00007f1ae218bee0 sp 00007ffe18581458 error 4 in libqxcb.so[7f1ae215d000+b5000]
[  152.973211] kscreen_backend[1976]: segfault at 18 ip 00007f6ec2cf9e38 sp 00007ffe34ea0320 error 4 in libqxcb.so[7f6ec2cb0000+b5000]
[  152.997937] ksmserver[1975]: segfault at 18 ip 00007f756b05de38 sp 00007fffb2c7fe80 error 4 in libqxcb.so[7f756b014000+b5000]
```

I was unable to find [where `xrandr` stores it's configuration](https://www.google.com/search?q=xrandr+config+file) and the X log doesn't seem to have anything amiss. **How should I troubleshoot from here, short of nuking `~` or even `/`?**

Note that this Kubuntu version uses Plasma 5, so I did a new install and not an upgrade from the previous version. The install went well, I've been using the system without any related problems for over a week now. This is a laptop computer that sometimes is connected to an external monitor.

**EDIT:** I just created a new user `test`, which also gets booted out of the supposed fail safe login mode. However, this user can log into its desktop just fine. Therefore the problem seems to be in a config file of my user. I'm currently bisecting them now, but I'm still open to ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been in one of the files in `~/.local/share/kscreen`. The laptop was connected to an external monitor when it was suspended, but without a monitor when the case was opened. **I must stress that I've done this quite a few times already on this setup, so I don't know why things broke this specific time.** Here are the files in question, for future reference *(yes, I'll probably be the one looking at this six months from now when I have the same issue again)*:

```
$ pwd
/home/dotancohen/.local/share/kscreen

$ ls
57aa46c23fd36deda7a9cfb885d7ecee  57aa46c23fd36deda7a9cfb885d7ecee_lidOpened  62f30f6a728bde980d325725a3f19f77

$ cat 57aa46c23fd36deda7a9cfb885d7ecee
[
    {
        "enabled": true,
        "id": "9dda8f0b1446d1e151e4d85bb529df5d",
        "metadata": {
            "fullname": "xrandr-unknown",
            "name": "LVDS1"
        },
        "mode": {
            "refresh": 60.001659393310547,
            "size": {
                "height": 768,
                "width": 1366
            }
        },
        "pos": {
            "x": 1080,
            "y": 464
        },
        "primary": true,
        "rotation": 1
    }
]

$ cat 57aa46c23fd36deda7a9cfb885d7ecee_lidOpened 
[
    {
        "enabled": true,
        "id": "9dda8f0b1446d1e151e4d85bb529df5d",
        "metadata": {
            "fullname": "xrandr-unknown",
            "name": "LVDS1"
        },
        "mode": {
            "refresh": 60.001659393310547,
            "size": {
                "height": 768,
                "width": 1366
            }
        },
        "pos": {
            "x": 1080,
            "y": 464
        },
        "primary": true,
        "rotation": 1
    }
]

$ cat 62f30f6a728bde980d325725a3f19f77 
[
    {
        "enabled": true,
        "id": "9dda8f0b1446d1e151e4d85bb529df5d",
        "metadata": {
            "fullname": "xrandr-unknown",
            "name": "LVDS1"
        },
        "mode": {
            "refresh": 60.001659393310547,
            "size": {
                "height": 768,
                "width": 1366
            }
        },
        "pos": {
            "x": 1080,
            "y": 464
        },
        "primary": true,
        "rotation": 1
    },
    {
        "enabled": true,
        "id": "0ffbea62a50d7b3aa8d01f0a7a422554",
        "metadata": {
            "fullname": "xrandr-E2342-211NDTC7A529",
            "name": "VGA1"
        },
        "mode": {
            "refresh": 60,
            "size": {
                "height": 1080,
                "width": 1920
            }
        },
        "pos": {
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0
        },
        "primary": false,
        "rotation": 2
    }
]
```

Dotan, just run this and be done with it:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.local/share/kscreen
```

And kisses to Meirav, Maayan, Ofek, and Ety while you're at it!